# How to run a robot's controller in multi processes or multi threads in webots?

Tags: robotics, webots

I want to have a controller that somehow runs 3 processes to run the robot's code.

I am trying to simulate a humanoid soccer robot in webots . To run our robot's code, we run 3 processes. One for the servomotors' power management , another one for image processing and communications and the last one for motion control.

Now I want to have a controller making me somehow able to simulate something like this or at least similar to it. Does anyone have any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news: the Webots API is thread safe :-)

Generally speaking, I would not recommend to use multi-threads, because programming threads is a big source of issues. So, if you have any possibility to merge your threads into a single-threaded application, it's the way to go!

If you would like to go in this direction, the best solution is certainly to create a single controller running your 3 threads, and synchronize them with the main thread (thread 0).

The tricky part is to deal correctly with the time management and the simulation steps. A solution could be to set the [`Robot.synchronization`](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/robot) field to FALSE and to use the main thread to call the `wb_robot_step(duration)` function every `duration` time (real time).

Comment: And how about separate processes? @fabienrohrer

Comment: The Webots libController is simply a shared library, and does not support to be called through separate processes. A solution could be to implement a controller as a wrapper to the libController API which is "listening" to the other processes through any IPC. In my point of view, this wrapper layer is a tedious solution to implement, but it can indeed work!

Comment: What about simply spawning child processes from your main controller program and communication with them through pipes or other IPC?

Comment: @olivier-michel That can be a possible solution but what I really care about is the procedure of running the robot to be similar to real world situation as much as possible that I am not sure while making child processes